# How can LIGO still detect the gravitational waves?

Tags: gravitational-waves, ligo

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/iphcyNWFD10) video by Veritasium (note: I don't have much physics knowledge). As I understand, at LIGO they detect the gravitational waves that were generated by the collision of the two black holes. How can they still measure these waves if the energy that they measure was released was only the last 10th of the seconds of the merging black holes (as I understand from the video)? As far as I understand, that would mean that there is only one peak that they can measure, which is that 10th of a second, but their experiment seems to be going on many years and they have made many measurements. How is this possible if the final collision was so short? What do they really measure then?

**Edit**

Basically my question comes down to: was that a "once in a lifetime chance" of measuring the waves? Have they been sitting there waiting for the exact moment and then do a measurement? It isn't something they can measure everyday?

Comment: They are seeing multiple BH collisions.

Comment: You're correct; the goal of detecting such events is to observe a ~0.1 second long signal every few months. The real challenge is having the equipment to be able to detect any event, however. In physics terms, 0.1s is an eternity.

Comment: You write "their experiment seems to be going on many years". The point here is that the detectors were improved in 2015, so that only now are we sensitive to these signals which have been passing the Earth undetected. In fact, the first detection happened soon after the upgrade, on 14 September 2015.

Comment: and an increase in sensitivity corresponding to a increase in distance of a factor x will give them access to a volume larger by x^3. Assuming events leading to a detectable emission of gravitational waves are evenly distributed in space, this corresponds to an increase of the 'chances' of seeing gravitational events by the same factor x^3 .

Comment: The attempts to detect Gravitational waves started over 30 years ago. Only with this latest kit has it become sensitive enough to detect them. They found the first wave within a few hours of it becoming operational (interesting story), and more of these events have now been seen. I had a lecture at my work from the Profs - interesting stuff. There is more to come!

Comment: "*Have they been sitting there waiting for the exact moment and then do a measurement?*" - no, you've got it the wrong way round. They don't have astronomers tell them when a collision will occur, then switch on their equipment and try to measure it. (The astronomers won't know it before they can watch it either). Instead, they have the measuring instrument running for months, and then they look at the data to find a pattern: Oh, this one tiny oscillation looks like there has been a black hole collision.

Comment: @PhilipOakley it would be more accurate to say that Advanced LIGO is the first version of the system sensitive enough to make detection's expected.  The previous iteration of the system - ~3-4x less sensitive - was run for several years before being shut down for upgrades.  27-64 times less likely to make a detection vs an implied detection rate of several times/year for A-LIGO meant that the odds were against a detection in the prior run; but less so than the odds of A-LIGO making a detection within hours of initial activation.

Comment: The search for a CW source from a rapidly spinning neutron star (from the several meter high 'mountains' expected to be on its surface) or a nearby pre-merger blackhole binary has similar if we're lucky (and there's one closer than any known instances) vs unless the physics are different than expected  odds of detection when comparing previous and current generation systems.  With the caveats that a finding a CW signal needs a [large super computer sized data reduction process](https://einsteinathome.org/) not a Eureka! and bad luck might delay success to the next generation instruments.

Comment: Worth of see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iphcyNWFD10

Comment: There's a second Veritasium video that sort of answers your question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViMnGgn87dg. Basically, they built the thing and within the first 1 hour of turning it on they detected the wave. Of course the scientists and engineers couldn't really believe it so waited for a few more months. Then when nothing else shows up they became suspicious that the recorded wave was a fake. So they took a look at it and eliminated all other explanations and published it. Basically, they were REALLY LUCKY

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is the data recorded from the first black hole merger:

[image: Black hole merger]

The figure is from [this paper by the LIGO collaboration](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102). A [PDF of the paper is available here](https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102).

The detectable signal lasted around 0.1 of a second, but the black holes were orbiting each other so fast that they completed about ten orbits during that time. Basically each oscillation in the data is one orbit.

The data immediately gives the rate of decay of the orbit as the black holes merge and the amplitude with which the gravitational waves are emitted, plus lots of other information hidden away in the detail. This is easily enough to confirm that this was a black hole merger and to measure the masses of the black holes involved.

Each pair of black holes only merge once, so this was the first and last signal detected from that particular pair of black holes. However the universe is a big place and there are lots of black hole binaries in it, so we expect black hole mergers to take place regularly. LIGO has already detected three mergers. The first (shown above) on 14th September 2015, then a second possible detection (at low confidence) in October 2015 and then a third firm detection on 26th December 2015.

LIGO took a pause to upgrade its sensitivity, but is now working again. As a rough estimate we expect it to detect a merger around one a month, that is roughly once a month a black hole binary will merge somewhere in the region of the universe that lies within LIGO's detection limits.

We don't know in advance where an when a merger will occur, so it's just a matter of waiting until one happens near enough to be detected.

Comment: So as I understand, this was really sort of a "once in a lifetime" measurement? There was only one try they could do, and if let's say there was a system failure, it was all for nothing?

Comment: @Derp: obviously we won't get any more info from the two black holes that have now merged, But there are lots of other merging black holes in the universe. Since the first detection there have since been two more black hole merger detections though one was borderline. When LIGO is running at its maximum performance we expect around one detection per month (very rough estimate).

Comment: @Derp There are more than two black holes in the universe.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I think your comment was really the answer to this question, and your answer was really a comment to this question...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I see Derp has edited the question so I have extended my answer to respond.

Comment: @Mehrdad that's actually true haha

Comment: Just wait until the ESA finishes eLISA. Three small-ish satellites trailing the earth orbit each 1 million kilometers apart, forming a Michelson interferometer. This will give us 360° triangulation capabilities with much, much more sensitivity than LIGO, provided they get it to work.

Answer (score 29):

You are right in that they are observing once in a life time (black hole's life time) event. But there are plenty of black holes, so few of such events may be detected within a year by LIGO.

The first announced observation was on September 14, 2015, while the second observation was on December 26, 2015.

Comment: As [Lawrence Krauss put it](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/1410.Lawrence_M_Krauss) "the universe is big and old and, as a result, rare events happen all the time."

Comment: If I was able to mark two answers as accepted I would mark yours too since you answered one of my questions as well.

Comment: Well, once in the lifetime of a particular pair of black holes. The merged hole could then merge with another hole, and then another, etc.

Answer (score 8):

To address this part of your question,

> As far as I understand, that would mean that there is only one peak that they can measure, which is that 10th of a second

No, there are between 4 and 5 peaks in that 0.1 second time span between 0.3 and 0.4s. The black holes were orbiting their center of gravity several dozen times per second just before the merge. (I believe it is half the frequency of the wave in the diagrams shown by John Rennie; please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: Yes, GW frequency is twice the orbital frequency.